# An array out of bounds error

Tags: java

I want to write code that splits a string into separate substrings each with 3 characters
and assign them to a string array for example the string "abcdefg" can be spit to "abc", "bcd", "cde", "efg" and these are assigned to a string array. I have the following code which is getting an error:

```
String[] words = new String[] {};
String sequence = "abcdefg";
int i;

for(i = 0; i <= sequence.length()-3; i++) {          

    words[i] = sequence.substring(i, 3+i);
    System.out.println(words[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code instead:

```
      String sequence="abcdefg";
      String[] words=new String[sequence.length()-2];
      int i;

      for(i=0;i<=(sequence.length()-3);i++){        
         words[i]=sequence.substring(i,3+i);
         System.out.println(words[i]);
    }
```

Or you could use arraylist of strings

Answer (score 6):

```
String[] words=new String[] {}; // empty array
```

you have empty array.

```
words[i] // when i=0
```

there is no index in empty `array` match with `0`th index.

Solution.

You can define the size of array at the moment you are define the `array`. The best way is get the `length` from `sequence`

```
String sequence="abcdefg";
String[] words=new String[sequence.length()];
```

Comment: thanks, how o i define the array so that the loop works

Comment: String[] words = new String[(int)Math.ceil(secuence.legth()/3)];

Comment: @X.L.Ant no it won't fail.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29

Answer (score 0):

You could get the length from the sequence string divided by the number of characters you want to store in order to know how big should your array be. For instance

```
String sequence="abcdefg";
int myLength = sequence.length/3;
String[] words=new String[myLength];
```

And then you could use that length to populate the array

```
 for(i=0;i<=myLength;i++){          

               words[i]=sequence.substring(i,3+i);

               System.out.println(words[i]);
    }
```